# I want to attach image in html email for this i am using base64 encoded image, but the problem is that image is not showing in the outlook app

Tags: html, outlook

Sending Image as base64 encoded image.

I want that this image will display in outlook mail but it is not showing.
How to get image as it is in outlook app.

Comment: This question was answered multiple time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968356/vml-base64-image?rq=1

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140486/base64-images-not-displaying-in-outlook-when-using-ejs-emailjs

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968356/vml-base64-image

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368949/cannot-embed-inline-image-in-outlook-when-image-is-in-barcode